# How to create a solution-level NuGet package?

Tags: nuget

How do I create a solution-level NuGet package.  That is, one that does not touch any projects, and is listed in .nuget\packages.config (not in any project-level packages.config files).

For example, psake and RavenDB.Server are solution-level NuGet packages.

I can't find anything in the docs for .nuspec files or nuget.exe that says anything about solution-level packages.  I can't find anything special in the build processes of those two projects when they call nuget pack.  In fact, I can't find a single search result at all about creating solution-level packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a brief comment from Phil Haack. It's from an [issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1049) on CodePlex:

> We already support this. Just don't put any content in the /Content
>   folder nor in the /Lib folder. If your package only has contents in
>   the /Tools folder, the package will not get installed in the project.

Haven't had a chance to test this out, but it sounds like what you're looking for.  A quick peek into the RavenDB.Server package (rename .nupkg to .zip) reveals a setup that is consistent with what Phil said in his comment. No content folder, no lib folder. Lots of files. The files are not in a `/tools` folder, so I think it's safe to presume that's not a requirement.

Comment: Yep.  I tried having nothing in Lib, but I did have some stuff in Content.  Thanks!