# How do I create a pure solution-level NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

**I want to create and distribute a NuGet package that when installed only installs solution-wide to the root `packages`-folder, referencing the package in the `.NuGet\packages.config` file.**

I have found some information on the NuGet package format in regards to this topic already and according to [NuGet FAQ](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-faq) this should be possible if one follow these guidelines:

> **What is the difference between a project-level package and a solution-level package?**
>
> A solution-level package has to be installed only once in a solution
>   to be available for all projects in the solution. A project-level
>   package must be installed separately in each project where you want to
>   use it. For solution-level packages, NuGet doesn't change anything in
>   a project, whereas in a project-level package it does. Typically, a
>   solution-level package installs new commands that can be called from
>   within the Package Manager Console window.

Another [Suggested SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982158/how-to-create-a-solution-level-nuget-package) states that the above should have worked too.

Thing is, I can't get it this to work. I have verified that my package has no lib or content directories:

[image: NuGet package contents]

I have put all the files to distribute in the `tools`-folder in the package, including the init.ps1` script top run on install.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and when I want to install the package:

1. I first of all have to select a project to install to. I had expected not having to specify this, as it is supposed to be solution-wide. `:/`
2. The `init.ps1` script does run and executes the commands as I want them to do. `:)`
3. But, a `packages`-folder is created in the project that I was forced to choose to get the installation done. I would have expected the `packages`-folder to be created in the solution-root. `:(`
4. Also, the `packages.config` file is created in the project-folder and not in `.NuGet\packages.config`, as I'd expect after reading the docs I have found on this. `:(`

Any suggestions on how to get this working? Is this a VS 2015 limitation or a NuGet 3 change (as I believe it was included in VS2015)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NuGet team [deprecated solution level packages](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522) in NuGet 3.0.

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521) about bringing them back in a way that is compatible with Visual Studio 2013 for a future version of NuGet.